# How to accurately add sound effects on each rigid body collision?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, audio

Emitting sounds with different intensity at rigid body collisions is what I want. I couldn't find a tutorial on it. Sorry I didn't post any reference image this time.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible.. I don't think such collision information is even available to python (unless perhaps you use the game engine).

Answer (score 6):

I would write a python script to keep track of the object's velocity. When the velocity suddenly decreases (on collision) I would play the sound, setting its volume based on how big the deceleration was.

Comment: Wow man now youve made some sense thank you

Comment: When it suddenly *changes*, not just *decreases*. And for the pro, make the sound depend on the material, its loudness depend on the impulse change, its stereo position depend on the location of the object (better: of the hit point) ...

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. so I wrote an add-on to do this - https://github.com/jacblo/Bake-Collisions-To-Sounds-addon

For the algorithm I based it on what @DevTim wrote, but with differences in acceleration rather than velocity so that faster and slower collisions can both be under the threshold